# Какой метод вызывается при использовании 'Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK'?

Tags: android, backstack, task

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Если пользователь заходит на активити А, а затем сворачивает его, то при открытии этого же активити (но уже через push-уведомление, а не историю приложений) - оно не пересоздается.

Для решения этой проблемы я использовал флаг `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`, но может произойти такая ситуация, что пользователь еще не закончил работу с текущим активити и не свернул его, но уже нажал на уведомление. Соответственно нужно показать ему диалог "Вы уверены? Вы выйдите навсегда!", но как? Какой метод вызывается при использовании 'Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK'?

Если никакой, то как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Вам не нужен FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK (уберите его) - при вызове существующего Activity отрабатывает метод

`Activity.onNewIntent(Intent intent)`

Переопределите этот метод и в нем опишите нужную вам логику (Показывать диалог / перезапуск Activity итд)

Comment: Идеально, проверю и поставлю ответом если сработает.

Answer (score 0):

Переопределить в `Activity` метод `onPause()`  вызвав в нём `AlertDialog`

[Ссылка на документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) там можно найти жизненный цикл `Activity`

Comment: 1) Ссылка битая;
2) Пользователь может сворачивать и разворачивать экран (ну, например, если придет СМС), приход уведомления ничем не регулируется, отправляется по определенному запросу других пользтвателей

Comment: @user3239600 значит нужно при нажатии на notification делать новый Task (intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), и там когда его закрываешь, основное не удаляется если конечно не делать чистку текущего Task, плюс придется повозиться с intent'ами. Тогда старый task уходит на паузу.